# force:recordData not working on Quick Actions

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I'm using "quick Action" on Task object in order to replace an old js button.
I tried to replace some ajax toll queries with "recordData" and use the data in the controller.
the result is always null.

I tried both - default and layoutType="FULL", same results null.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" controller="wsc_checkResponse">
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Task" />

<force:recordData layoutType="FULL"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetFields="{!v.record}"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdate}" />
    <aura:attribute name="taskWhoId" type="id"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    fields="WhoId"
    targetFields="{!v.taskWhoId}"
    targetError="{!v.recordLoadError}"
    recordUpdated="{!c.onTaskLoadingCompleted}"
    />
    <div class="Record Details"> 
        <lightning:card iconName="standard:account"  >
            <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
                <p class="slds-text-heading--medium"><lightning:formattedPhone title="taskWhoId" value="{!v.record.Id}" /></p>
                <p class="slds-text-heading--medium"><lightning:formattedPhone title="taskWhoId" value="{!v.record.taskWhoId}" /></p>
            </div>
        </lightning:card>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

ctrl.js

```
({
    recordUpdate: function(component, event, helper){
        console.log('record',component.get("v.record"));
    },
    onTaskLoadingCompleted : function(component, event, helper) {
    var taskWhoId = component.get("v.taskWhoId");
        console.log('taskWhoId',taskWhoId);

    }
})
```

task record or at last WhoId is expected but nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other base Lightning components, including [`<lightning:recordEditForm>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation), `<force:recordData>` does not support the Task or Event objects.

The list of supported objects is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm), in the Lightning Aura Components Developer Guide. The underlying limitation appears to come from the [UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm), which doesn't support Task and Event.

Comment: I think there is something else going on in the quick actions, as I am using opportunity and doesnt load, however when i use my lightning component inside a vf page it loads correctly